# omp_set_max_active_levels() and function call

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openmp

Anyone know the scope of `omp_set_max_active_levels()`, assuming function A has a omp parallel region, and within the region, each thread of A makes a call to library function B, and within library function B there are 2 levels of omp parallelism.

Then, if we set active omp level in function A to 3 (1 in A and 2 in B),  can that ensure that library function B's parallel region work properly?

Answer (score 0):

if `omp_set_max_active_levels()` is called from within an active parallel region, then the call will be (should be) ignored.

Comment: I think the behavior in that case will be implementation defined, see section 3.2.15 of the latest standard

Answer (score 0):

According to the OpenMP 4.0 standard (section 3.2.15):

> When called from a sequential part of the program, the binding
>   thread set for an `omp_set_max_active_levels` region is the encountering
>   thread. When called from within any explicit parallel region, the
>   binding thread set (and binding region, if required) for the
>   `omp_set_max_active_levels` region is implementation defined.

and later on:

> This routine has the described effect only when called from a
>   sequential part of the program. When called from within an explicit
>   parallel region, the effect of this routine is implementation defined.

Therefore if you set the maximum number of nested parallel region in the sequential part of your program, then you should be ensured that everything will work as expected on any compliant implementation of OpenMP.

Comment: if I set `omp_set_max_active_levels(2)` inside a function, does it take effect through out the whole code, i.e. will it take effect in a separate function too?